# In a universal iOS app, only on iPad Pro 12 inch landscape a MKMapView renders as a totally black map. Any suggestions?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios-simulator

I am maintaining a iOS project, so I still don't have a complete understanding of it. I have a fullscreen MKMapView that renders in a completely black map only on iPad Pro 12 inch Landscape left and right. I have tried to isolate the problem using git and it comes out that the problem occurs only if I have a LaunchScreen xib or storyboard set as the launch screen of the app. If I remove the Launchscreen everything works. I am certain this does not depend on some problem in the startup code, because If I start the App in Portrait, then I switch to landscape, the map renders in black. Any suggestions ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit:

Only when the problem occurs and the map renders in black, I have several occurrences of this error in the Xcode log:

ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1360.30.2.5.58/geo/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1194: Framebuffer incomplete, incomplete attachment

Comment: Same issue on simulator and on device ?

Comment: I don't have a real device to test with unfortunately